# Installation error psycopg2 termux Android

Tags: android, python-3.x, psycopg2, termux

How can I install psycopg2 on my termux Android?

I tried

```
pip install psycopg2==2.2
pip3 install psycopg2-binary

LDFLAGS="-L/system/lib64/" CFLAGS="-I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/" pip install psycopg2-binary
```

But everytime got this error
[image: Error:]

Read other answers on stack overflow but they don't work.

```
apt-get
sudo
```

Commands Requires rooted Android and I'm not rooted.

> I would be grateful if someone help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install PostgreSQL itself before installing python client**

`pkg install postgresql`

If it doesn't help, try to install dev version and other dependencies

`pkg install postgresql-dev python make clang`

After that install postgresql client `pip3 install psycopg2`

Found working solution here:
https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/835